# Search for Matches by Searching for text in Django model field

Tags: python, django, caching, search, model

I have a model similar to this

```
class Item(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    words = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True)
```

I would like to be able to search through the objects, and return he best matches for a specific query. 'Best match' can be defined as the closest text based result to the `words` field, (I can write a function that returns an integer representation of 'closeness' no problem, the model search and cacheing are the problems).

Ideally, each time a search is made, if it has been made before, only new elements since the last time the query was made should be searched (the other results have already been cached). I can not find a django module that achieves this.

Some info:
  DB: postgres
  Connector: psycopg2

Comment: I ended up using elastic search with the Django plugin, as the pattern matching inside Django was too expensive. https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks, I was searching the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use difflib to order your query, so it will put at the top [-1] the best match.

```
>>> import difflib
>>> a = ["spam", "eggs", "spammy", "eggy"]
>>> b = 'spam'
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, b).ratio())
['eggy', 'eggs', 'spammy', 'spam']
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, as it would pull the entire dataset from my database every time a search is preformed before being able to parse it at all